# Tabela preenchida incorretamente HTML e Java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-datatables

Estou com a seguinte situação, quando insiro os dados oriundos do banco de dados, a minha tabela é populada da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aparece essa mensagem: "No data available in table", como se os dados que são inseridos não fossem para a tabela.

O código do HTML é esse:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table  table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>CNPJ</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Responsável</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                <tbody></tbody>                
             </table>
```

E o código do java script é esse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/exemplo',
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                var tr = "<tr>" +
                    "<td>"+ val.id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+ val.id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+ val.id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+ val.id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+ val.id + "</td>" +

                    "</tr>";
                $(tr).appendTo('tbody');

            });
        }
    });   
});
```

Logo as funções da tabela como paginação e pesquisa também não funcionam. Porém se eu insiro os dados manualmente no HTML entre as tags tbody a tabela funciona normalmente. Alguém sabe do que se trata?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: simplemente voce tem 6 tags TH, mas `$.each` so esta colocando 5 TD dentro de cada TR. Acho que pode ser isso

Comment: Olá, eu fiz o teste e não faz diferença, o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o componente (jQuery DataTables) para "gerenciar" os dados da tabela. Porem está incluído linhas manualmente. Esses dados, incluindo após a inicialização do DataTable, não são reconhecidos por ele. Talvez você não tenha reparado. Mas alem do problema com a mensagem, estas linhas não são levadas em conta na páginação, ordenação ou busca.

[Aqui tem um exemplo](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) bem simples de como deve ser utilizados os recursos do componente para a criação de novas linhas:

Aplicado ao seu problema sem a requisição Ajax, pois o código fornecido não possibilita reproduzir este cenário.

```js
var t = $('table').DataTable();
t.rows.add( [[ 
       "1",
       "João",
       "123.456",
       "teste@teste",
       "aaaaaaaaa"      
        ]
      ]).draw();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" class="table  table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>CNPJ</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Responsável</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                <tbody></tbody>                
             </table>
```

Porem, ao trabalhar dessa forma, teu sistema perderá desempenho quando houver muitos registros. Independentemente de estar utilizando Ajax.

Para grandes volumes de dados, recomendo utilizar um outro recurso do componente. [Documentação aqui](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). Porem, vale lembrar que dessa forma você estará passando a responsabilidade de controlar a paginação e fazer a ordenação para o servidor. Portando terá um pouco mais de trabalho.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou certinho! Porém vou seguir sua dica, pois irei lidar com uma grande quantidade de dados.